# Which Azure Functions App's Subscription plan best suites calling a .exe console application on daily basis

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, hosting, azure-functions

I am working on a SharePoint online site which contain a custom list. now i want to host a console application inside Azure Function App, and trigger it to run daily @ 1:00 am. the console application will be doing the following:

1. integrate which sharepoint custom list, to get all the list items which have their `due date = Today`. the integration will be either using REST API or client object module (did not settle on which appraoch i will follow).
2. after that the console application will send an email contain the details about  those items to a sharepoint group.

now i access our customer Azure account,and inside the Function App's create form, i find these 2 options inside their Subscription list:-

[image]

but i have these 2 questions:-

1. as i know from my reading, i should have an option titled "Pay-As-You-Go" inside the subscription plan not sure why it is missing?
2. second question is about how Azure will be billing us for hosting the console application inside azure function app? i mean, Azure usually reduce the credit as users access certain resource. but in our case no one will be accessing the console application, and the console application will mainly be requesting data from the sharepoint list. if i understand things correctly (which i doubt that i am currently doing!!) the console application will be accessed one time daily when it is being triggered @1:00 is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `#1` you should contact subscription owner and ask which plan is better.

For `#2` - Azure calculates pricing for functions based on how many memory you selected and how many seconds your function runs. It's called GB/s in their [terminology](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/).
In your case, it will calculate memory * amount of seconds when your console app is running.

For example even in a case, if you selected 1.5GB and your function runs a maximum of 10 minutes, running every day (avg. 30 per month), you pay [nothing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator):

[image]

One note though, that functions use storage account, and you might pay something for storage, but in case of single function running 30 times per month, it's very small, about 1-2$ per month (from my experience).

I recommend you to expand Azure functions timeout to 10min beforehand because it's 5min by [default](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan).